# Scroll content only over background image jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

Im making a website for mobile devices with jQuery Mobile, HTML and CSS and I've just set a background image. I want the image to stay the same while scrolling the rest of the content over it.

Comment: `background-position:fixed`?

Answer (score 1):

add this to your css

```
.yourClass{background-attachment:fixed;}
```